# Identity theorem in $p$-adic geometry/analysis

Tags: p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic-numbers, berkovich-geometry

If one wants to do $p$-adic analysis and geometry, it is often bad so adapt "naively" complex analytic ideas, basically because $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is disconnected. The modern approach to this is, to my knowledge, the theory of rigid analytic spaces and Berkovich spaces. For instance in the theory of Berkovich spaces, the maximum modulus principle holds. I'm curious what we can say about the Identity theorem. Does it hold in any of the $p$-adic geometries?

I've been told to think of rigid analytic spaces as varieties and (Huber's-)adic spaces as schemes with Berkovich being closer to an "analytic" object, so probably I'd expect it (if at all) to hold there.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about the identity theorem. Could you write down the statement you would like to see? Anyway, I am pretty sure it should be true, and if it holds for one of the theories, it certainly does for the others. The spaces may be presented a bit differently, but they are mostly equivalent.

Comment: I'm happy to do so. I choose the name based on what it is called on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).  Let $D$ be some domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ (i.e. open an connected). If two holomorphic functions $f$,$g$ on $D$ agree on a subset $S$, which has an accumulation point, then in fact they agree on $D$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You probably mean $\mathbb{C}$ and not $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: This also holds at the "more elementary" level of Krasner's theory of analytic elements.

Comment: Do you have a nice reference for this?

Comment: @curiousmathguy I suppose you are asking me for the reference (you can "call me" by writing my username after an @). The original references are the papers by Krasner in the Comptes Rendus (which you can find online at gallica). Also, you may look at Alain Robert's book on p-adic analysis.

Comment: Especially this one: "Prolongement analytique dans les corps valués complets: démonstration de la loi d'unicité: fonctions analytiques uniformes", 
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 239 (1954), 745–747.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me assume that you have an analytic function $f$ defined on a closed one-dimensional unit disc, which is to say the spectrum of the Tate algebra $k\{T\}$. Then, Weierstrass preparation theorem tells you that $f$ may be written as a product of a polynomial $P$ and a nowhere vanishing function. If $P$ is non-zero, it has only finitely many zeroes, and so does $f$.

As you see, it can really be turned into a statement about Tate algebras, so the precise theory you want to work with does not really matter.

Please, let me know if you had a more general context in mind.

Comment: Thanks you Jérome! This is exactly what I hoped for, thanks for showing this to me!